# Converting values in Dataframe to lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe from parsed matches in Dota containing chat information with columns of match_id, slot and the text. Each row represents one line of text. Now, I want to group those rows such that every slot (representing a player) has all texts assigned to them in a list of values. The slots are number from 0-9, so I don't want the texts of slot 0 in match number 5 be grouped together with the text of slot 0 in match number 1. How would I go about doing that? Is it possible to do inplace  or would I have to create a new Dataframe from scratch?

Here's an example input:

**match_id, slot, text**
 0,         0,   "gg"
 0,         2,   "good game"
 0 ,        2,   "well played"
 1,         0,    "glhf"
 1,         6,    "u2"
 1,         0,    "thx"
...,       ...,  ...

what I would want is to summarize it into this:

**match_id,   slot,    text**
 0,         0,   "gg"
 0,         2,   {"good game", "well played"}
 1,         0,    {"glhf", "thx"}
 1,         6,    "u2"
..., ..., ...

I hope this brings some clarity

Comment: Can you please share example input and output you want?

Comment: Edited the Op, hope this helps ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'match_id' :[0,0,0,1,1,1] ,'slot':  [0,2,2,0,6,0] ,'text':  ['gg','good game','well played' ,'glff' , 'u2' , 'thx'] })
df.groupby(['match_id','slot'])['text'].apply(list).reset_index(name='text_list')
```

Output:

```
   match_id  slot            text_list
0         0     0                 [gg]
1         0     2  [game, well played]
2         1     0          [glff, thx]
3         1     6                 [u2]
```